# Angularfire, Prevent function return to initial value when reload page

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, angularfire2

I have a function in my `service.ts` for pushing data to my firebase. I made more variables to store math calculation's result. They are variable for storing number of submitter and the option they choose. When the first load of `localhost:4200` and I submitted 1 male and 1 female, I have 50% for each. The problem is when i reload the `localhost:4200` page and submitted another data (for example I add 1 more male),  the result/ratio is reset to 0 again (and become `100% male` and `0% female`). I didn't delete my data in my firebase.

```js
//service.ts
selectedData: App = new App();

dataList: AngularFireList < any > ;
getData() {
  this.dataList = this.firebase.list('data');
  return this.dataList;
}

percentList: AngularFireList < any > ;
getPercent() {
  this.percentList = this.firebase.list('percent');
  return this.percentList;
}

male: number = 0;
female: number = 0;
percentMale: number = 0;
percentFemale: number = 0;
insertData(data: App) {
  this.dataList.push({
    nama: data.nama,
    email: data.email,
    gender: data.gender,
  });

  if (data.gender == 'Male') {
    this.male++;
  } else if (data.gender == 'Female') {
    this.female++;
  }

  this.percentMale = this.male / (this.male + this.female) * 100,
    this.percentFemale = this.female / (this.male + this.female) * 100,

    this.percentList.update("percentKey", {
      male: this.male,
      female: this.female,
      percentMale: this.percentMale,
      percentFemale: this.percentFemale,
      //percentMale: this.percentMale = this.male/(this.male+this.female)*100,
      //percentFemale: this.percentMale = this.male/(this.male+this.female)*100,
    });
  console.log('percentMale', this.percentMale + '%');
  console.log('percentFemale', this.percentFemale + '%');
}

<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->
```

If i remove the `=0` on the variables it returns error `First argument contains NaN in property`.

```js
//component.ts
ngOnInit() {
  var x = this.AppService.getData();
  x.snapshotChanges().subscribe(item => {
    this.dataList = [];
    item.forEach(element => {
      var y = element.payload.toJSON();
      y["$key"] = element.key;
      this.dataList.push(y as App);
    });
  });

  var q = this.AppService.getPercent();
  q.snapshotChanges().subscribe(item => {
    this.percentList = [];
    item.forEach(element => {
      var w = element.payload.toJSON();
      w["$key"] = element.key;
      this.percentList.push(w as App);
    });
  });
}

this.AppService.insertData(this.AppService.selectedData);
```

Please let me know if more snippets are needed. Thank you in advanced.